# Solr boolean query with phrase match

Tags: solr, edismax

I want to execute a solr query with boolean clauses.

But the phrase match is executed on the complete query and not on the individual queries which are created.

I am using eDismax Query Parser

Is it possible to have both boolean conditions in query and phrase matches ?

Eg:
Query -

```
(gear AND cycle) OR (black AND cycle)
```

The parsed query for this is

```
"+((+(query:gear)~0.01 +(query:cycle)~0.01) (+(query:black)~0.01 +(query:cycle)~0.01)) (phrase:\"gear cycle black cycle\")~0.01"
```

As can be seen the query conditions are correct but I want the phrase match on "gear cycle" or "black cycle"

Comment: Would `"gear cycle" OR "black cycle"` work? Is the order important (and not just the distance) - how about `cycle gear` and `cycle black`?

Comment: Adding qoutes in query will not return results where gear and cycle are present but are not together. I want to return such results. I just want to boost results where both occur together and return other matching results. Ordering is also important when doing a phrase boost.

Comment: Could you use a regular query and then a boost query (bq) with the phrases? That will allow using the ComplexPhraseQueryParser with `inOrder=true`.

Comment: boost query will not solve the use case exactly. with phrase boost, will be using the ps parameter to define phrase slop. Is it not supported by solr to provide different strings to match for query and phrase boost ?

Comment: Not sure why using `bq` or `boost` won't work? Could you elaborate?

Comment: If phrase slop is set as 2 then a phrase match for "black cycle" will match documents like "black colour cycle"

Not sure how to achieve the same using bq.